# Как посмотреть исходники системных библиотек?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Как в `Visual Studio` посмотреть исходники системных библиотек по `F12`?

Есть ли они в открытом доступе и по какой лицензии?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно воспользоваться сторонними утилитами интегрирующимися в Visual Studio, например [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) или [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Но эти утилиты платные. Если нет принципиальной необходимости декомпилировать библиотеки прямо из Visual Studio можно воспользоваться бесплатными декомпиляторами, например [IL Spy](http://ilspy.net/) или [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: Они исходники подцепляют или декомпилируют библиотеки?

Comment: @SmitJohnth Resharper умеет и подцеплять исходники и декомпилировать. .Net Reflector скорее всего тоже самое.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: @SmitJohnth я тоже дополнил ответ.

Comment: Дык а исходники есть? Или они закрытые?

Comment: @SmitJohnth какая-то часть уже стала открытой, найти их можно здесь https://github.com/dotnet Но, пока еще не все в общем доступе.